# Why do I get an error "name 'play' is not defined" when I think it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

Full error:

```
line 10, in <module>
    colour = play()
NameError: name 'play' is not defined
```

I can't seem to find a reason for this issue anywhere on here. I am trying to assign the returned string to the variable colour but it is refusing to recognise the function "play".

```
import random
Funds = 10
Bet = "Red"
betsequence = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
counter = -1
totalcount = 0

while(Funds > 0):
    counter = counter + 1
    colour = play()
    if colour == Bet:
        Funds = Funds+(betsequence[counter]*2)
        counter = -1
    else:
        Funds = Funds-betsequence[counter]
    print(colour)
    totalcount = totalcount

def play():
    random.seed(a=None, version=2)
    rannum = random.uniform(0,1)
    result = rannum*14
    if (result > 1) and (result < 8):
        return "Red"
    elif result < 1:
        return "Green"
    else:
        return "Black"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the name before it is first used. In your case, moving the definition of `play` to before the `while` loop will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, realised this a few seconds after posting. Was confused as this is how I usually lay out my C# code and this is literally the first thing i've written in python. Sorry for the waste of time!