# Why do I get "NameError: name 'B'/'C'/'V' is not defined"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

```
Question = input("Welcome to the meal chooser program. The base cost is $9.99. Would you like to choose beef, chicken, or the vegetarian option?:")
if Question.casefold() == "beef":
    print("Thank you. Your total cost is","$",'{:.2f}'.format(B))
elif Question.casefold() == "chicken":
    print("Thank you. Your total cost is","$", '{:.2f}'.format(C))
elif Question.casefold() == "vegetarian":
    print("Thank you. Your total cost is","$", '{:.2f}'.format(V))
B = 9.99*1.02
C = 9.99*1.025
V = 9.99*1.03
```

Whenever I run this and input chicken, beef, or vegetarian it prompts me with a message that says that the values of B, C, and V are not defined, but they are.

Comment: Your title indicates the program is not running but they you get a message saying something ? (which one is it?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an error "name 'play' is not defined" when I think it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123196/why-do-i-get-an-error-name-play-is-not-defined-when-i-think-it-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code runs (barring jumps like function calls and class initializations) linearly, top down. Because you initialize your variables at the bottom, your code has not created the values when you arrive at your if-else block. If you put your variables first, the code will run fine.